# Move files according to pattern matching

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have some files whose name looks like this:

```
XXXXX_S1_X_XX_X.txt
XXXXX_S2_X_XX_X.txt
XXXXX_S3_X_XX_XXX.txt
S4_X_XX_X.txt
XXXXX_S5_XX_X.txt   
...
```

I created a list of folders named: `S1`, `S2`, `S3`, .... I would like to move the file `XXXXX_S1_X_XX_X.txt` in the folder `S1`, the file `XXXXX_S2_X_XX_X.txt` in the folder `S2` and so on. I wrote this simple loop but I don't know how to copy/move files according to the pattern matching S* in the corresponding folder:

```
for i in My_list_of_folders.txt
do 
  dir=${i%.txt}
  mkdir "$dir"
  cp "$i" "$dir"
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slightly modified loop:

```bash
for pattern in S1 S2 S3 S4; do
   mkdir -p ./"$pattern"
   for filename in ./*"$pattern"*; do
       [ ! -f "$filename" ] && continue
       mv -i "$filename" "$pattern"/
   done
done
```

This loops through the pattern strings `S1`, `S2`, `S3` and `S4`.  The inner loop uses the current pattern string to look for names in the current directory that contains the string anywhere in it. It skips non-regular files (like the directories `S1`, `S2` etc. themselves) and moves everything else that matches to the appropriate directory for that pattern string.

As slm points out in comments (now deleted), the operations in the inner loop may in this case well be shortened into just

```bash
[ ! -f "$filename" ] || mv -i "$filename" "$pattern"/
```

or

```
[ -f "$filename" ] && mv -i "$filename" "$pattern"/
```

If you have overlapping patterns, such as `S1` and `S11`, then you will need to do the longer patterns first.

Comment: I like it very much but it does not work with S11, S12,....*S1* are taken together.

Comment: @Elb No it does not, but that wasn't part of the question. You would have to do longer patterns first, e.g. `S11` before `S1`.

Comment: Oh yes! You're right. To avoid typing "S*".... many times I replaced the first line with: for pattern in S{1..17};....probably this caused the mv, only in the S1 folder, of all the "S1*" items.

Comment: @Elb `S{17..1}` would work.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative:

```
for i in S{4..1};do 
  mkdir -p $i
  while read line; do 
    [ -f "$line" ] && mv "$line" $i
  done < My_list_of_folders.txt
done
```

#### How it works:

- `S{4..1}` - uses shell expansion to construct the names of dirs
- `mkdir -p $i` - forces creation of directory
- `while read ... < My_list_of_folders.txt` - loops through lines in file
- `[ -f "$line" ]...` - moves each file to corresponding S dir

**NOTE:** You can adjust the glob ({4..1}) to whatever range suites your use case. To deal with anything larger, we're ordering things in reverse to deal with any overlap S20 .... S1, hence the `S{20..1}` type of definition of our glob.