# OSX13; how to mv series of x numbers of file chunks simultaneously to the series of directories

Tags: bash, zsh, macos, mv

I have a following list of files;

```
260704       96 -rw-r--r--    1 MacStudio      staff               47131 Jul 28 20:18 ./GSM7673474_30_CC0022.barcodes.tsv.gz
260705     6264 -rw-r--r--    1 MacStudio      staff             3206621 Jul 28 20:18 ./GSM7673474_30_CC0022.features.tsv.gz
260706   592096 -rw-r--r--    1 MacStudio      staff            303149616 Jul 28 20:18 ./GSM7673474_30_CC0022.matrix.mtx.gz
260707       88 -rw-r--r--    1 MacStudio      staff               44397 Jul 28 20:18 ./GSM7673475_31_CC0022.barcodes.tsv.gz
260708     5800 -rw-r--r--    1 MacStudio      staff             2967665 Jul 28 20:18 ./GSM7673475_31_CC0022.features.tsv.gz
260709   481960 -rw-r--r--    1 MacStudio      staff            246761628 Jul 28 20:18 ./GSM7673475_31_CC0022.matrix.mtx.gz
260710       80 -rw-r--r--    1 MacStudio      staff               38322 Jul 28 20:18 ./GSM7673476_32_CC0022.barcodes.tsv.gz
260711     6104 -rw-r--r--    1 MacStudio      staff             3123868 Jul 28 20:18 ./GSM7673476_32_CC0022.features.tsv.gz
260712   430808 -rw-r--r--    1 MacStudio      staff            220569913 Jul 28 20:19 ./GSM7673476_32_CC0022.matrix.mtx.gz
260713       80 -rw-r--r--    1 MacStudio      staff               38152 Jul 28 20:19 ./GSM7673477_33_CC0053.barcodes.tsv.gz
260714     6160 -rw-r--r--    1 MacStudio      staff             3152423 Jul 28 20:19 ./GSM7673477_33_CC0053.features.tsv.gz
260715   404888 -rw-r--r--    1 MacStudio      staff            207300291 Jul 28 20:19 ./GSM7673477_33_CC0053.matrix.mtx.gz
```

I want to move these files to name matching directories. I created directories matching "GSM7673474_3x"  as follows;

```
drwxr-xr-x@ 2 MacStudio  staff  64 Nov 10 18:36 GSM7673474_30/
drwxr-xr-x@ 2 MacStudio  staff  64 Nov 10 18:37 GSM7673475_31/
drwxr-xr-x@ 2 MacStudio  staff  64 Nov 10 18:37 GSM7673476_32/
drwxr-xr-x@ 2 MacStudio  staff  64 Nov 10 18:38 GSM7673477_33/
```

Based on an answer by Kusalananda in [Move files according to pattern matching](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/456445/516047) I came up with a following script to move files to name matching directories.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d |rg -o "GSM\d+.*" > dir.name

for i in $(cat dir.name) ; do echo $i;for filename in ./*"$i"* ;do mv -i "$filename"/ $i ;done ;done
```

This works fine with a mv warning but I am looking for a way to mv each of 3 files to directories in order.  For example, these files,

```
GSM7673474_30_CC0022.barcodes.tsv.gz
GSM7673474_30_CC0022.features.tsv.gz
GSM7673474_30_CC0022.matrix.mtx.gz
```

will be in the `GSM7673474_30` directory and next 3 sets of files;

```
GSM7673474_31_CC0022.barcodes.tsv.gz
GSM7673474_31_CC0022.features.tsv.gz
GSM7673474_31_CC0022.matrix.mtx.gz
```

to the next directory, `GSM7673474_31` and so forth.

Since I am seriously getting stuck figuring out, I'd really any inputs in this.

My system;

```
                  'c.          MacStudio.local
                 ,xNMM.          -----------------------------
               .OMMMMo           OS: macOS 13.6 22G120 x86_64
               OMMM0,            Host: Mac13,2
     .;loddo:' loolloddol;.      Kernel: 22.6.0
   cKMMMMMMMMMMNWMMMMMMMMMM0:    Uptime: 10 hours, 53 mins
 .KMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWd.    Packages: 240 (brew)
 XMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMX.      Shell: zsh 5.9
;MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM:       Resolution: 2048x858
:MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM:       DE: Aqua
.MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMX.      WM: Quartz Compositor
 kMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWd.    WM Theme: Blue (Light)
 .XMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMk   Terminal: iTerm2
  .XMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMK.   Terminal Font: Monaco 10
    kMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMd     CPU: Apple M1 Ultra
     ;KMMMMMMMWXXWMMMMMMMk.      GPU: Apple M1 Ultra
       .cooc,.    .,coo:.        Memory: 3475MiB / 131072MiB
```

Comment: Do what the [tag:bash] tag you used instructs "For questions about Unix shells in general, use the /shell tag instead. For shell scripts with errors/syntax errors, please check them with the shellcheck program (or in the web shellcheck server at https://shellcheck.net) before posting here." then post your corrected script and let us know if you still have a problem.

Comment: If you do still have a problem then try the parts of your script one step at a time. Does `mv -i "$filename"/ $i` do what you expect for 1 value of `i`? If so, does `for filename in ./*"$i"* ;do mv -i "$filename"/ $i ;done` do what you expect? And so on.

Comment: Ed, Thanks for a suggestion.  Next time I will post a script question with a script tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like just a matter of

```
autoload -Uz zmv
zmv '(GSM<->_<->)_*' '$1/$f'
```